# SQLAlchemy.Один ко многим к себе

Tags: python, база-данных, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Могу ли я сделать отношение в SQLAlchemy, так, чтобы экземпляр объекта хранил в себе несколько других экземпляров этого же класса?Чтобы было понятнее: у меня есть таблица пользователей, и каждый пользователь может иметь,например,подписчиков, которые тоже являются пользователями. Можно ли это реализовать при помощи `sqlalchemy.orm.relationship` или других инструментов SQLAlchemy?Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можете. У вас в таблице Users, должно быть поле id_user и pid_user (ид родительского пользователя).

Модель такой таблицы на алхимии будет следующей:

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id_user = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    pid_user = Column(ForeignKey('user.id_user', ondelete='CASCADE', onupdate='CASCADE'), index=True)
    name = Column(String(15))

    respondent = relationship('User', remote_side=[id_user])
```